# JavaScript get value of query string parameter

Tags: javascript, url, split, location

I can't find any splitter solution JS to obtain one parameter in this URL
https://www.test.be/fr_BE/home/forms/test-test-salon.html?configId=f4q8s9z1&ucpBaseurl=https%253A%252F%252Ftest.client.ucp.cloud&model=F56&motorization=Diesel

The part I want to isolete is the model id, model=F56, in this case I want to isolate "F56"

I tried this script without success:

```
var srcID = "11111"; // Insert your src ID here
var typeID = "11111"; // Insert your type ID here
var category = "m1111"; // Insert your category value here
var axel = Math.random() + ""; var a = axel * 10000000000000;

// Grab Data Layer
var dataLayerApi = digital.tracking.getInstance(dataLayer);
var digitalData = dataLayerApi.getPageObject((window.minidtm.actPageId     !== undefined) ?  window.minidtm.actPageId  : dataLayerApi.getCurrentPageIndex());

var path = document.location.pathname;
var pathHirarchy = path.split("&");

if(path.match("\/fr_BE\/home\/forms\/.*\/.*") != null) {
            // Get Model Info
            var u1 =  pathHirarchy[1] //U1 - Produit
            var u2 =  pathHirarchy[5].split(".")[0] //U2 - Sous Produit
}
else {

 var u1 = "notApplicable";
 var u2 = "notApplicable";
}

var DCtag = document.createElement("iframe");
DCtag.src = "https://" + srcID + ".fls.test.net/activityi;src=" + srcID + ";type=" + typeID + ";cat=" + category +
        ";u1=" + u1 +";u2=" + u2 + ";dc_lat=;dc_rdid=;    tag_for_child_directed_treatment=;ord=1;num=" + a;
DCtag.width = "1"; DCtag.heigth = "1"; DCtag.frameborder = "0"; DCtag.style =    "display:none"; DCtag.async = true;
document.body.appendChild(DCtag);
```

Do you have an idea ? Expertize in ?

Big big Thanks !
Ludo

Comment: `new URLSearchParams(document.location.search).get('model')`

Answer (score 7):

You could use [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

```js
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const model = params.get('model');
```

If `model` isn't present in the query string `params.get('model')` will return null.

For more information on `URLSearchParams.get` see the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/get)

Comment: The question didn't specify what browsers it must run on, but this has the failing that even now it's not supported by the latest version of MSIE : caniuse.com/#search=URLSearchParams

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regexp:

```js
const url = 'https://www.test.be/fr_BE/home/forms/test-test-salon.html?configId=f4q8s9z1&ucpBaseurl=https%253A%252F%252Ftest.client.ucp.cloud&model=F56&motorization=Diesel';

const result = url.match(/model=(.*?)&/);
const model = result[1];

console.log(model);
```

**EDIT:**

I'm gonna leave this answer here, but bflemi3's answer is better.